# Prove that $(\log_2n)^{\log_2n} \in o( 2^{(\log_2n)^2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

Let $f(n) = (\log_2n)^{\log_2n}$ and $g(n) = 2^{(\log_2n)^2} $

I want to show that $f(n) \in o(g(n))$.

$f(n) = O(g(n))$ if there exist positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that
$0 \leq f(n) \leq cg(n)$ for all $n ≥ n_0$

I guess it makes intuitive sense if we perform a a substitution $z = \log_2n$ we get $\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{z^z}{2^{z^2}}$ which I remember as converging to $0$. But I'm not sure exactly why. How do you prove this rigorously?

I guess taking derivatives comes to mind which gets me $\frac{d}{dz}z^z = z^z(\log z+1)$ and $\frac{d}{dz}2^{z^2} = 2^{z^2}2z\log(2) $ which isn't that helpful for me.

Comment: Hint: $$a^b=2^{b\log_2a}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the log of the quotient tends to $-\infty$:
$$\log\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\log_2n\log_2(\log_2n)-(\log_2n)^2\log2=-(\log_2n)^2\biggl(\log2-\frac{\log_2(\log_2n)}{\log_2n}\biggr).$$
The second factor tends to $\log2\;$ since $\;\log_2u=o(u)$.